# Devexpress unload usercontrol after save form

Tags: c#, user-controls, devexpress

i have a main form which is containing a menu.
when i click a menu button there is an usercontrol is loading panel control in main form:

```
splitContainerControl1.Panel2.Controls.Add(new Moduller.userControlStokListesi() { 
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill 
});
```

And there is a form on UserControl. when a user fill that form and hit the save button i want to remove that user control form from panel control.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand your question correct, you want to remove the instance of `Moduller.userControlStokListesi` from the Panel2 ?

There are several ways to achieve this. You can remove all controls from a panel this way:

```
splitContainerControl1.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
```

You can also remove specific items:

```
splitContainerControl1.Panel2.Controls.RemoveByKey("the key of your control");
```

Or if you want the user control removes itself from the panel, you can call this snippet within the user control instance:

```
SplitContainerControl splitPanel = (SplitContainerControl) this.Parent;
splitPanel.Panel2.Controls.Remove(this);
```